# Need to Format Date

Tags: php, format

I am trying to show on the screen a date in the format such as Monday October 4, 2013 using the data from MySQL table. The date is stored in DATE format. I am using the following and I get an error:

```
echo "<td class='date' colspan='8'>" .date($row['draw_date'],'l F j, Y'). "</td>";
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the parameters backwards for [`date()`](http://php.net/date) and you need to convert your date to a timestamp before using it in the `date()` function.:

```
date($row['draw_date'],'l F j, Y')
```

should be

```
date('l F j, Y', strtotime($row['draw_date']))
```

Comment: Would this work if the `$row['draw_date']` is not a Unix timestamp?

Comment: Actually no. Seeing your comment made me re-read their question and I now see they are not storing the data as a timestamp which means it must be converted as such. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function expects a Unix timestamp as its second parameter and you're now supplying the format as the second parameter.

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

You need to first convert your date string to a Unix timestamp using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) and you can use it in `date()` to get the date in required format:

```
date('l F j, Y', strtotime($row['draw_date']))
```

Refer to the documentation for more information: [`date()`](http://php.net/date)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is going to be returning the date in string format, e.g. `2013-10-07`. You can **NOT** use that string as the timestamp in PHP's `date()` function. That function expects a UNIX time stamp, which is a simple integer. Either format your date in MySQL using [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and simply output the string, or use MySQL's [unix_timestamp()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to convert the native DATE into a unix timestamp which you CAN feed into PHP's date system.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following from different suggestions and it seems to work. Thanks for your help.

```
$row['display_date'] = strtotime($row['date']);
    echo "<td class='date' colspan='8'>".date('D M d, Y', $row['display_date']). "</td>";
```